# Android - Listviews

Tags: android

I wanted to make my ListViews the size of the actual content. For example if there's 20 items I want it to display the 20 items **without making the list itself scrollable like it is now.**

It looks like this atm: The lists are very small and they are scrollable.
https://i.gyazo.com/eb8902a17936f54a2271b51abe228607.png

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.ArchiveFragment">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Tube Data"
            android:textColor="@color/AMOB_yellow"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tubeData_list">
    </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Tool Data"
            android:textColor="@color/AMOB_yellow"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolData_list">
    </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_clear_all"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"
            android:text="Clear all"
            android:textColor="@color/AMOB_gray"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this, might be you gotta solution for it :-

```
 Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(yourlistview);
```

add this method :-

```
public static class Utility {
        public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter == null) {
                // pre-condition
                return;
            }

            int totalHeight = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
                listItem.measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }
```

It will not Scroll but u can get the size of the actual content as you want.